# Optical flow based tracking of quadrilateral points in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to track a quadrilateral using optical flow method in a video sequence. The quadrilateral is provided by user at the start. It works properly very short duration but as object rotates, the tracking start to fail. Can someone just how can I improve this tracking? The object is of interest is a number plate on motorbike which is has both rotation and translation motion in the sequence. The initial four points (four corners of number plate) are selected by the user.
I've also tried used SHIFT descriptor but I'm not getting enough matching points between successive frame for region of interest.

```
 std::vector<cv::Point2f> feature_prev, feature_next;
        std::vector<uchar> status_vector;
        std::vector<float> status_error;
        cv::TermCriteria termcrit;
        cv::Size subPixWinSize, winSize;

        cv::Mat prevFrame;
        cv::Mat currFrame;
 feature_next.push_back(cv::Point2f((float)refRoi.P1().x,(float)refRoi.P1().y));
        feature_next.push_back(cv::Point2f((float)refRoi.P2().x,(float)refRoi.P2().y));
        feature_next.push_back(cv::Point2f((float)refRoi.P3().x,(float)refRoi.P3().y));
        feature_next.push_back(cv::Point2f((float)refRoi.P4().x,(float)refRoi.P4().y));


     cv::cvtColor(srcCpy, currFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            cv::equalizeHist(currFrame, currFrame);

           // cv::Mat srcMat(srcGray.operator const IplImage *());
           // dst = src;
            if(!feature_prev.empty())
            {
                status_vector.clear();
                status_error.clear();
                feature_next.clear();
                cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevFrame, currFrame,feature_prev,feature_next,status_vector,status_error, winSize, 5, termcrit, 0, 0.001);
                size_t i, k;
                for( i = k = 0; i < feature_next.size(); i++ )
                {
                    if( !status_vector[i] )
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    feature_next[k++] = feature_next[i];

                    circle( srcCpy, feature_next[i], 3, cv::Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8);
                }

                feature_next.resize(k);
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most similar to you requirements is TLD algorithm,

take a look here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2qR60hrD2w

you can find description here

http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/Z.Kalal/tld.html

The paper:

http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/Z.Kalal/Publications/2009_olcv.pdf

And the source code here:

https://github.com/zk00006/OpenTLD

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll start looking into.